# Dynamic Size CollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a layout which uses multiple collectionviewcells to lay themselves out. At the moment I am using a static height but as we all know there is no telling the size of what the content will be especially in my case because it will be text taking up the majority of the cell. I have not been able to find a way an accurate way to size the cell based off of the size of the textView in the cell along with the padding.

So in short I am asking is there anyway to size the content based off of the size of the things in the collectionVIew.

This is what I currently have for the cell

```
import UIKit

class DetailCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var eventDescription: String? {
        didSet{
            print("got description")
            guard let eventDescription = eventDescription else {
                return
            }
            eventDetails.text = eventDescription
            updateWithSpacing(lineSpacing: 10.0)
            textViewDidChange(eventDetails)

        }
    }




    lazy var eventDetails: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        guard let customFont = UIFont(name: "NoirPro-SemiBold", size: 15) else {
            fatalError("""
        Failed to load the "CustomFont-Light" font.
        Make sure the font file is included in the project and the font name is spelled correctly.
        """
            )
        }
        textView.font = customFont
        textView.textColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 32, green: 32, blue: 32)
        textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.textAlignment = .natural
        return textView
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    fileprivate func setupViews(){
        addSubview(eventDetails)
        eventDetails.delegate = self

        eventDetails.snp.makeConstraints {
            make in
            make.top.equalTo(detailsLabel.snp.bottom).offset(15)
            make.left.right.equalTo(self).inset(5)
            make.height.equalTo(50)
        }

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    //MARK: - Update Line Spacing
    func updateWithSpacing(lineSpacing: Float) {
        // The attributed string to which the
        // paragraph line spacing style will be applied.
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: eventDetails.text!)
        let mutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        // Customize the line spacing for paragraph.
        mutableParagraphStyle.lineSpacing = CGFloat(lineSpacing)
        mutableParagraphStyle.alignment = .justified
        if let stringLength = eventDetails.text?.count {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: mutableParagraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))
        }
        // textLabel is the UILabel subclass
        // which shows the custom text on the screen
        eventDetails.attributedText = attributedString

    }

}

extension DetailCell: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print(textView.text)
        let size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width - 5, height: .infinity)
        let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)
        textView.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
            if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
                constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is my size for the cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 350.0)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out the height of cell as you

```
extension String {
func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont?) -> CGFloat {
    guard let fontValue = font else {
        return 0
    }
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: fontValue],
                                        context: nil)
    if boundingBox.height >= 80 {
       return 80
    }
    return ceil(boundingBox.height)
 }
}
```

after that you can use this string extension to get height value and pass it to collectionView delegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let feature = cellData.arrayOfData[indexPath.row]
    let height = feature.height(withConstrainedWidth: collectionView.frame.width,
                                font:"FontYouAddedToTextView")
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: height)
}
```